# How to create a method contains an array that compare the elements to get the highest one?

Tags: java, arrays, loops

I have a class named Player consists of the following instance variables:

```
private String name, position;
private int numGames, numGoalsScored, numGoalsConceded;
```

The class also has two constructors, one has name and position as parameters and the other is a copy constructors. 
I'm asked to create a class called `Team`, this class should contain many methods to control the `Player` class. One of the method is `bestPlayer()`, this method should get the player of the best performance, which is calculated be the `getPerformance();` method that has written in the player class.

**My question is: How to create a method to get the best player?**
I wrote the following code but sadly it didn't work:

```
/* Get the best player */
public Player bestPlayer()
{
    if (playerNum == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("Error: Empty team!");
    }
    double max = 0;
    int index = 0;
    for ( int i = 0; i<playerNum; i++ ){

        if(playerList[i].getPerformance() > max) {
            max = playerList[i];
        }
    }

    return playerList[index];
}
```

I keep getting that "incompatible types" error!

Answer (score 0):

I see an incompatible type with `max = playerList[i]` assuming that playerList is an array of type Player. How can you assign a Player to an double? Other than that, I see a few other problems with the method as well.